# Mark as safe for scripting activeX InternetExplorer object in access with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, activex

I try to get the DOM from VBA with access. But I can't get the DOM.

```
Dim objHTML As Object
With IE
    .Navigate2 "http://myanimelist.net/animelist/Alaanor"
    WaitIE
    Set objHTML = .Document.body.innerHTML
End With
```

But I have read the documentation of [IE.Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and he said:

> Warning   If the document object type is not marked safe for scripting, this property returns Nothing.

That exactly the problem I have. But I can't find how solve it.

Anyone can help me ?